# Developing ActiveX control for Windows CE

Tags: compact-framework, activex, windows-ce

I have a few questions on Windows CE.

1.Does Windows CE supports use of ActiveX objects in HTML page?

2.Can ActiveX controls be developed/written in .Net C# with Visual Studio 2008 for use on Windows CE 5.0 IE Browser?

3.Is it necessary to install .NET CF in handheld device?

The requirement is to get local information about the device(IP, hostname,  etc.) from the html page. I am currently doing R&D to find out how to achieve this. What we thought of doing is to call a custom ActiveX dll from html file which will run locally on the hand held device to get the required information and pass it to the html page.

If anyone knows of other ways to achieve this then please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the CE browser supports COM objects that implement IObjectSafety.
2. No.  The controls must be written in C++.  To make it even more fun, they *must* be compiled for the device OS and processor architecture.  The reason you can't create them in .NET is because the Compact Framework doesn't support EE hosting, so native code cannot call managed code on a device (inside our outside a browser).
3. This is orthogonal since the answer to #2 is no.

There may be another way to achieve your goal, but it's not clear what the actual problem is to me.  You have a page served up from the device that needs to show the IP address to a browser on the same device?  How does that user get to that page?  If it's from an app, you could have the app either report it directly or have the app get the IP and save it into an HTML page which you then browse to.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, if your customer won't allow the install of the CF, then they likely aren't going to want you to install an ActiveX component either (and if you could do .NET components, it would have required the CF be installed, so your requirements would have precluded doing so even if it were supported).

Why not write a simple C program that does what your CF program does (i.e. saving device info to an HTML file) and that requires no additional framework installs?

Comment: Well, We have a static html page which contains links to our URL (there may be multiple links). The user clicks on one of these links to navigate to our application URLs. Its in these page that the device information needs to be displayed. We had made an app which gets the device information and saves it into the html page. We had used .NET CF, but the client are unwilling to install CF in their device.

Comment: It does make sense. Very Helpful. I will go ahead with it.            Can you please point me to any resource, Documents, Links you know of on how i can write a the C program and deploy it to my Handheld device?

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is being served from a webserver, then it already knows the IP address that it is talking to (i.e. there might be some proxies in the way, but if they're behaving, they can tell you who the remote client really is), so you might not need to install anything.

As for the version of Internet Explorer installed on CE 5, I don't believe it supports ActiveX at all, but you could install a .Net application instead of using a webpage to solicit information?

Comment: Is it possible to get the client IP address behind proxies and VPN??